# How to write magento 2 media query only for 1366*768

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to write styles only for 1366*768 resolution .. How can write Media query that effect only 1366*768 in magento 2 way

Comment: did you mean CSS only apply to 1366 width and 768 width ?

Comment: @Pawan Yes only effect for 1366

Comment: @Did you try my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min-width` and `max-width` for this.

If you want to target specific width, you can use same value i.e 1366 in both `min-width` and `max-width` like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Media Example</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background: red;
        }
        @media (min-width:1366px) and (max-width:1366px) {
            body{
                background: blue;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Here!!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```